# PIL attribute error

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I tried to do a scrip with Pillow but i have a instance method error
the code is something like that

```
import StringIO
import subprocess
from PIL import Image
command = "fswebcam -q --no-info --no-banner --jpeg -d /dev/video0 -i 0 -r 100x75 -"
imageData = StringIO.StringIO()
imageData.write(subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True))
imageData.seek(0)
im = Image.open(imageData)
print buffer1[1,1]
```

and when i tried to execute them i get

```
File "prueba.py", line 17, in main
    print im[1,1]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 528, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: __getitem__
```

so what is wrong?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't subscript the image object directly, you must use the [`load` method](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.Image.load) to create an access object.

```
im = Image.open(imageData)
buffer1 = im.load()
print buffer1[1,1]
```